# GWT: How to programmatically reload CellBrowser?

Tags: gwt, cellbrowser

I'm using GWT 2.1's [CellBrowser](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/index.html?overview-summary.html) with a custom `TreeViewModel`. The TreeViewModel in turn uses an `AsyncDataProvider` to fetch data dynamically. This all works beautifully- when the user clicks on a node my AsyncDataProvider fetches the results via RPC, and the CellBrowser dutifully displays them.

I feel silly for not being able to figure this out, but how can I programmatically tell the CellBrowser to reload (and display) the data? I'm guessing that I need to somehow get a handle to the AsyncDataProvider for my root node and then call updateRowData() & updateRowCount() on it, but I don't see an obvious way to query the browser (or its model) for the root DataProvider.

I guess I could add code to my AsyncDataProvider constructor that looks for a null argument, and by that means recognize "hey, I'm the root" and store a reference somewhere, but that seems hackish. Surely there's a better way to do this.

Apologies for dumping so much code here, but I don't know how to boil this down to anything simpler and still provide enough context.

**My AsyncDataProvider:**

```
private static class CategoryDataProvider extends AsyncDataProvider<Category>
{           
    private Category selectedCategory;

    private CategoryDataProvider(Category selectedCategory)
    {
        this.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<Category> display)
    {
        new AsyncCall<List<Category>>()
        {
            @Override
            protected void callService(AsyncCallback<List<Category>> cb)
            {
                // default to root
                String categoryId = "-1";
                if (selectedCategory != null)
                {
                    categoryId = selectedCategory.getCategoryId();
                }

                // when a category is clicked, fetch its child categories
                service.getCategoriesForParent(categoryId, cb);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<Category> result)
            {
                // update the display
                updateRowCount(result.size(), true);
                updateRowData(0, result);
            }
        }.go();

    }
}
```

**My model:**

```
private static class CategoryTreeModel implements TreeViewModel
{
    private SingleSelectionModel<Category> selectionModel;

    public CategoryTreeModel(SingleSelectionModel<Category> selectionModel)
    {
        this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
    }

    /**
     * @return the NodeInfo that provides the children of the specified category
     */
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value)
    {
        CategoryDataProvider dataProvider = new CategoryDataProvider((Category) value);

        // Return a node info that pairs the data with a cell.
        return new TreeViewModel.DefaultNodeInfo<Category>(dataProvider, new CategoryCell(), selectionModel, null);
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the specified category represents a leaf node
     */
    public boolean isLeaf(Object value)
    {
        return value != null && ((Category) value).isLeafCategory();
    }
}
```

**And finally, here's how I'm using them:**

```
        CategoryTreeModel model = new CategoryTreeModel(selectionModel);
        CellBrowser cellBrowser = new CellBrowser(model, null);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like a lot of people are having this [same issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5533).  Here's how I handled refreshing the data from an AsyncDataProvider.

First, create an interface that adds the ability to refresh data provider by wrapping the AsyncDataProvider's protected onRangeChanged method.  For example...

HasRefresh.java

```
public interface HasRefresh<HasData<T>>{
  /**
   * Called when a display wants to refresh 
   *
   * @param display the display to refresh
   */
   void refresh(HasData<T> display);

}
```

Then the CellTable needing to be refreshed can then call into it through an Activity or however your controller logic is setup.

```
/**
* A custom {@link AsyncDataProvider}.
*/
public class MyAsyncDataProvider extends
            AsyncDataProvider<Entity> implements HasRefresh<Entity> {

            public void refresh(Entity display){

                  onRangeChanged(display);
             }

             /**
         * {@link #onRangeChanged(HasData)} is called when the table requests a
         * new range of data. You can push data back to the displays using
         * {@link #updateRowData(int, List)}.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onRangeChanged(
                HasData<Entity> display) {
            currentRange = display.getVisibleRange();
            final int start = currentRange.getStart();

            dataServiceQuery = context.getEntities();

            dataServiceQuery
                    .execute(new DataServiceQueryHandler<Entity>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onQueryResponse(
                                DataServiceQueryResponse<Entity> response) {


                            updateRowCount(response.getCount(), true);
                            updateRowData(start, response.getEntities());

                        }
                    });

        }// end onRangeChanged()

    }// end MyAsyncDataProvider class
```

Comment: typo on "HashRefresh" but otherwise +1 ! :)

Comment: Why is everybody voting up this answer?  The one below is much better - a single line change that does all of this.

Comment: updateRowData(start, response.getEntities()) update all displays for provider, you can use updateRowData(display, start, response.getEntities()) instead. But display.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(display.getVisibleRange(), true) is still better :)

Comment: See the answer from Hugo. It actually answeres the OP's question regarding CellBrowser, not CellTable.

Answer (score 7):

Found out now, the following code is basically the same but from the HasData interface instead of using AsyncDataProvider.

```
HasData<T> display;
...
display.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(display.getVisibleRange(), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why affablebloke's answer is marked as "correct" and upvoted so much!?

Caffeine Coma asked about updating a **Cell Browser** and not a **Cell Table**, that are totally different things!

For me, the following trick worked: 
I define the `DataProvider`s outside of the `TreeViewModel` and pass them as an argument to the constructor. In my case they provide empty data structures at the beginning.

Now you have a reference to the `DataProvider`s from "outside" in order to update the Cell Browser.

Example:

```
private class MyTreeViewModel implements TreeViewModel {

    AbstractDataProvider<MyDataStructure> myDataProvider;

    public MyTreeViewModel(AbstractDataProvider<MyDataStructure> myDataProvider)
    {
        this.myDataProvider = myDataProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
        if(value == null)
        {
            // Level 0
            return new DefaultNodeInfo<MyDataStructure>(myDataProvider, new MyCellImpl());
        }
    }
}


AbstractDataProvider<MyDataStructure> myDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<MyDataStructure>(new ArrayList<MyDataStructure>()); // or AsyncDataProvider
MyTreeViewModel myModel = new MyTreeViewModel(myDataProvider);

CellBrowser<MyDataStructure> cellBrowser = new CellBrowser.Builder<MyDataStructure>(myModel, null).build();

/*
  here you can do some stuff, for example, bind the CellBrowser to a template with UiBinder
*/

/*
 if you use a ListDataProvider, do
*/

myDataProvider.setList(myDataStructureFromSomewhere);
myDataProvider.refresh();

/*
 if you use an AsyncDataProvider, do
*/

myDataProvider.updateRowData(..., myDataStructureFromSomewhere);
myDataProvider.updateRowCount(...);
```

Comment: Thank you providing this answer. It works perfectly. I had been wondering how to refresh a CellBrowser for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
 List<TreeGridRecord> dataToTable = ....

int firstPosition = this.pager.getDisplay().getVisibleRange().getStart();
this.dataProvider.updateRowData(firstPosition, dataToTable);

int rowCount = this.pager.getPageStart() + dataToTable.size();
this.dataProvider.updateRowCount(rowCount, exactCount);
```

Where the "pager" is a SimplePager to control the table pagination.

Hope this helps!